# How to force foreign key generation between an @Entity and a @ElementCollection?

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

Here is my code:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="POSTS")
public class Post {
    @Id
    private Integer id;

    @Column(unique=true, nullable=false)
    private String slug;

    @ElementCollection(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @CollectionTable(
      name = "POSTS_TAGS", 
      joinColumns = { 
          @JoinColumn(name = "POST_SLUG", referencedColumnName = "SLUG")
      }
    )
    private List<String> tags = new ArrayList<>();

}
```

Hibernate generate two tables: `POSTS` and `POSTS_TAGS`.
However it doesn't generate a foreign key in `POSTS_TAGS`.

If I remove the `joinColumns` property from `@CollectionTable` annotation, it generates a foreign key with the `id` primary key.

How can I instruct Hibernate to generate a foreign key with the `joinColumns` property?

**Hibernate 4.3.7**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunatelly you cannot instruct Hibernate to generate a foregin key, as it tries automatically to generate them. Because they are generated in other contexts (like for `@ManyToOne` annotations or when you leave out the `@CollectionTable` annotation), I am pretty sure it is a bug.